# Querying JSON array in Redshift?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

Are you able to query a field within an array in a Redshift JSON column?

I have the following JSON:

```
{"sort_details":[{"sort_by":"name","order":"asc"}]}
```

Is it possible to query anything lower than the highest level element in Redshift?  I've tried using

```
json_extract_path_text( myjson , 'sort_details' , 'sort_by' )
```

but got a null row back.  I'm guessing that being an array and conceivably returning multiple results per record, this might not be possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use nested JSON functions:

```
json_extract_path_text(
    json_extract_array_element_text(
        json_extract_path_text( 
            myjson, 
            'sort_details'
        ), 
        0
    ), 
    'sort_by'
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(myjson, 'sort_details', 0, 'sort_by')
```

This also works, but it's not documented in AWS Doc